# monetdb_check_subquery() is too strict

Tags: r, monetdb

This function is inherited from the current stable release of `dplyr`, but I gather it has been migrated to `MonetDB.R`

It fails on any occurrence of the strings "limit" and "offset", which in my case happen to be column names, but could also be values.  Perhaps a warning would be more appropriate?  Sorry for not knowing regex well enough to suggest anything more precise.

```
> getAnywhere("monetdb_check_subquery")[2]
function (sql) 
{
    if (grepl("ORDER BY|LIMIT|OFFSET", as.character(sql), ignore.case = TRUE)) {
        stop(sql, " contains ORDER BY, LIMIT or OFFSET keywords, which are not supported.")
    }
}
```

And thank you for a very handy package.

Comment: If your column names exactly match "LIMIT" or "OFFSET" then a regex solution is just likely to fail. You would probably need a proper SQL parser which is much trickier to implement. Really, your best bet in this scenario is probably to over-write the function. Are you calling it directly, or what's the code that triggers the error for you?

Comment: I agree with you about regex.  I've changed my column names to avoid the problem for now.  `monetdb_check_subquery()` is a non-exported function that is triggered by an initial call to `tbl(my_db, sql('SELECT ...')`

Comment: @MrFlick, that is exactly the problem... But since ORDER BY or LIMIT can only really occur at the end of the query, this might be a possibility. Will try to incorporate this in the next release of MonetDB.R